# Find the corresponding row and column number to an indexed element in a matrix

Tags: arrays, r, matrix

I would like to get (and store) the corresponding row and column number in a matrix, eg. to element number 12.

```
adj.m <- diag(c(3,2,1),nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
```

now i want to find the row and corresponding to element  4 or 5 or any.
`adj.m[4]` gives back the value(0), but I want to get and store in a variable  the corresponding row and column numbers (1 and 2 in this case).

I assume its a simple command, but I could not formulate the question, that Rseek or Google returns an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `i` is your index and `m` is your matrix, then the row and column of `i` can be obtained with

```
get_row <- function(i, m) (i-1) %% ncol(m) + 1
get_col <- function(i, m) ((i-1) %/% ncol(m)) + 1
```

Usage is, e.g.,

```
get_row(4, adj.m)
get_col(4, adj.m)
```

---

Actually, Iain's answer is possibly more natural.  You can wrap it into a function as

```
get_row_col <- function(i, m)
{
  x <- array(seq_along(m), dim = dim(m))
  which(x == i, arr.ind = TRUE)
}
```

This also works in more than two dimensions, e.g.,

```
m <- array(1:24, dim = 2:4)
get_row_col(1:24, m)
```

Comment: Thank you all, very nice solutions! 
lain's answer is maybe more natural, but it basically generates a 2nd matrix which can consume memory, I assume (in case of an 1000*1000 matrix eg.)

Answer (score 3):

I think `which()` will work

```
x <- matrix(nrow=3, ncol=3, data=seq(1:9))
which(x==6, arr.ind=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the arrayInd function:

```
arrayInd(7, .dim=c(3,3))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    3
```